Can two positive electric conductors attract each other in some cases?
Can two positive conductors attract each other in some cases?
In my opinion, let me denote the two conductors by $Q_1,Q_2>0$. Suppose $Q_1>>Q_2$ and $Q_2$ is really small. Let a tip of $Q_1$ be very sharp so that the charge here is really high. Then put the sharp tip of $Q_1$ really close to $Q_2$. By interaction, the side of $Q_2$ which is close to the sharp tip of $Q_1$ may be negative, attracting the conductor $Q_1$.
Is it possible? Can you give me some advice on simulating it in Mathematica or any other applications?
If it is possible if $Q_1,Q_2$ are both sphere? Can you help me to calculate and prove this?

You dont need to do anything particularly special. Two spherical ones will do, if they are close enough together. Preferably if at least one of them is very small.

This is a good question, I was so used to working with point charges that I've never considered this scenario where a conductor induces an opposite charge on the other one and they repel, seemingly defying Coulomb's law. I wonder what the output of this experiment will be

Can two positive electric conductors attract each other in some cases? - Yes.  Electrostatic Force between Charged Conducting Spheres and Electrostatics of two charged conducting spheres

A point charge and a conducting sphere will do it (and that case is simple to compute)
